# Cant access router configuration page but internet can b accessed from one device, from another device its vise versa

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I have two routers, router A has the internet connection and I made the router B as extender/repeater.

Router A IP is 192.168.1.1 Router B IP is 192.168.1.2
[image]

I saw that the DHCP has to be disabled in router B. So I disabled the DHCP but I cannot access the configuration page in wireless mode and also in wired mode.

So I reset the router and I didn't turn of the DHCP.
[image]

```
Please have a look on network details images for more clarification.
```

Now what I can see is,

```
my mobile is getting access to the internet, but cant access the configuration page(192.16.1.2).
```

[image]

```
my laptop is also connected in the same router, but no internet access and can access the configuration page(192.16.1.2).
```

[image]

What kind of problem is that I'm facing?
Should I statically assign the IP to the devices I'm connecting with?
Could any one help me to solve this..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you bridged the connection between router 1 and router 2. That's the only way for you to get Internet access on router 2. If you do that, you can leave DHCP on on both (recommended), and connect more devices to either router. We'd also need to know how router 2 is connected to router 1. If it's via an Ethernet cable, make sure it's plugged into the WAN port. If it's via WiFi, it's going to be more difficult to sort your issue...

Comment: @Didier yes it is bridged through wireless connection. The thing is I'm getting internet connection and cant able to access the router 2 configuration page in mobile. But in laptop I'm not getting internet and able to access router 2 configuration page.

Comment: Given your network configuration, you'll get access to the admin page of the access point you're connected to. In the case of a bridged connection, you need NAT (Network Address Translation) to access router 1's admin page from a device connected to router 2. You can try a variation on the http://192.168.100.1:8080/ address. Yours may differ from this: there may be different numbers after 168, but in principle, that's how to do it: aim at an IP address via the 8080 (http) port. Try all the variations you can think of, based on the actual address of router 1.

Comment: NB: 8080 is an alternate http port (main port is 80), so you might want to try with port 80 too, if 8080 doesn't work.

Comment: @Didier May I know whats causing the internet connectivity to get connected with laptop?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but let's put it like this: your laptop can be connected to your access point, and that's good, and still not be able to connect to the Internet, because something's not right in the way your access point is set up. If router 2 was connected to router 1 via Ethernet, you could set one network adapter (Ethernet) on router 1 as a bridged connection, and leave the other network adapter (WiFi) on router 1 as NAT, and benefit from both, because you'd get direct access to Internet from router 1's WiFi, and indirect access via router 2.

Comment: @Didier To my way of thinking, I'm concerned that its because of the DHCP. Though it is enabled, it works in two different ways. IP assignment could have caused the problem. Did you see that? Mobile IP and system IP differs. where mobile IP is 192.168.0.101 and system IP differs 192.168.1.111.

Comment: That's because your mobile is connected via WiFi directly to router 1, whereas your laptop is connected via WiFi to router 2. The laptop can access the admin page in router 2 alright, but can't access the Web because router 2 doesn't have access to the Web itself. On router 1, you must choose between bridging your WiFi and using it as is, in NAT mode; you can't do both. The best setup would be an Ethernet cable between routers 1 and 2, so that you can get direct Internet access from router 1 (WiFi) and router 2 (WiFi as extension of router 1 Ethernet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107134/discussion-between-silver-shine-sarath-and-didier).